# Javascript Grammar Checking

Tags: javascript

Could someone kindly correct my javascript work?

```
   if (screen.width 800 =>) {
       alert(".");
       var redirect=confirm("You are on the mobile site. Would you like to visit our full site instead?");

   if (redirect == true) {
       window.location.href = 'http://TEXTHIDDEN.com/'; 
   }
   else {
       return true;
   }
```

My aim:
If a user visits the mobile version of my site, it will prompt them to go to the desktop page, if they are using a pc or high-res tabet (width 800+).

Thanks

Comment: `if (screen.width 800 =>) {` - what is that? Reverse lisp? Try `  if(screen.width >= 800) {`

Comment: a) It's "grammAr", not grammer and 2) what does that have to do with your request?

Comment: Kindly describe your specific issue that you are facing instead of dumping some code and some specifications.

Comment: 1) I shall change the title 2) Because I have used code from different places and mashed it all together. I have little javascript experience and I thought things were in the wrong places.

Comment: I will follow as Benjamin Gruenbaum said: change the screen.width attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably roughly what you're looking for:

```
if (screen.width >= 800) {
   var redirect = confirm("You are on the mobile site. Would you like to visit our full site instead?");
   if (redirect) {
       window.location.href = 'http://TEXTHIDDEN.com/'; 
   }
}
```

You should invest some time in learning some javascript basics, and use tools like [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) to check your syntax in the future.

Comment: Thank You. Sorry too, should have tried to do it myself first. I will learn basics soon, but my priority now is getting my site back on track.

Answer (score 0):

It's `>=`, not `=>`, and your use of the operator is wrong, there should be an operand on each side of it. Also, you are missing the ending bracket of the outer `if` statement:

```
if (screen.width >= 800) {
   alert(".");
   var redirect=confirm("You are on the mobile site. Would you like to visit our full site instead?");

   if (redirect == true) {
     window.location.href = 'http://TEXTHIDDEN.com/'; 
   }
   else {
     return true;
   }
}
```

Aside from the syntax, you can also omit the comparison with `true`, as the variable `redirect` is a boolean value, so it can be used as a condition itself:

```
if (redirect) {
```